# Android Studio not starting after new patch

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I recently downloaded a patch for Android Studio of approximately 206 MB, but after that it's not starting properly anymore.
 The menu screen will load up, but I am not able to create new project, open existing projects, or even configure my Android SDK location through **Settings > Project Struture**. I have tried deleting/(renaming and importing) the ~/.AndroidStudioXXX folder, but it doesn't help.

OS: Ubuntu 14.10
Java Version: 1.8.0_91
Android Studio Version: Android Studio 2.2.3  Build #AI-145.3537739

Error Log:

```
    [7002]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - tried to access method com.android.sdklib.AndroidVersion$AndroidVersionException.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V from class com.android.sdklib.AndroidVersionHelper 

    java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.android.sdklib.AndroidVersion$AndroidVersionException.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V from class com.android.sdklib.AndroidVersionHelper
    at com.android.sdklib.AndroidVersionHelper.create(AndroidVersionHelper.java:71)
    [7006]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_76-release 
    [7007]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
    [7007]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
    [7007]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Linux 
    [7007]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action:
```

Comment: Full log available here: http://collabedit.com/wytq9

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue long back, easy way to fix this is to reinstall Android Studio

Comment: After uninstalling, try deleting the files related to the android studio in the AppData folder.